# Flowplayer is not autobuffering but loading whole video

Tags: flowplayer, buffering

I am using flowplayer to play flash video. I've set autobuffering to true but it is still loading the whole video before playing. I've also tried setting bufferlength: 2, but no better. When using HTML5 (code not shown), it works correctly. Any ideas? Looks like JWPlayer does the same thing - although it at least shows that something is happening. Is this an issue with Flash that the swf has to process the whole file first?

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="640" height="360" 
    data="./flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

    <param name="movie" value="./flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />                            

    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "./videos/<? echo $video ?>.mp4", "autoPlay":true, "autoBuffering":true}}' />                            
</object>
```